# Rails Problems in IE - double storing in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've got several problems with a Rails 4.2.1 and Ruby 2.1 application when testing in IE. If I save something to a database and do a redirect, the values are saved twice in the database.

Does anyone have this as well?

Save Methode in controller:

```
if request.post?
  @question.attributes = params[:question]
  if @question.save
    flash.now[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
    update_answers params
    redirect_after_save @question
  end
end


def update_answers params
  if !params[:add].nil?
    params[:add].each do | id, data |
      answer = Answer.new
      data[:question_id] = @question.id
      answer.update_attributes data
    end
  end 
end


def redirect_after_save q
  if params[:action_after_save] == 'back'
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
    redirect_to :controller => :lessons, :action => :edit, :id => q.lesson_id
  end
  if params[:action_after_save] == 'new'
     flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
     redirect_to :action => :new, :id => q.lesson_id
  end

  if params[:action_after_save] == 'test'
       flash[:notice] = I18n.t("flash.saved")
     redirect_to :action => :test, :id => q.id
  end
end
```

I'm not using turbolinks.

View Code:

```
<%= f.submit t("main.save"), :icon => :save %>
<%= t("question.or_save_and") %>:
<% [[t('question.after_save_back'), 'back'],
    [t('question.after_save_new'), 'new'],
    [t('question.test_question'), 'test']].each do |it| %>
    <%= f.submit(it.first, :disable_with => "saving",
             :onclick => "$('#edit_question').append('<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action_after_save\" value=\"" + it.second + "\" />');",
             :icon => :save) %>
<% end %>
```

this is the Code which is called during saving.

```
def multiple_choice
@question = Question.find params[:id]
return false unless check_authorization @question
add_edit_breadcrumbs @question

if request.post?
  @question.attributes = params[:question]
  if @question.save
    flash.now[:notice] = t("flash.saved")
    SLACKNOTIFIER.ping "Bevor update answers"
    update_answers params
    SLACKNOTIFIER.ping "After update answers"
    redirect_after_save @question
  end
end
 end
```

the whole code is called twice in IE ...

Comment: According to the logs, is the request made twice as well? What version of IE?

Comment: Yes its eine twice. And its in all verwions the same. In edge AS well.

Comment: Could you please also show the relevant code in your view?

Comment: of course. Code is added above.

Comment: Do you have an Idea whats going wrong?

Comment: Its only a problem in IE and Edge.

Comment: I've added some more code above. Problem only comes when I do save and back.

Comment: I figured out when I leave this: `:disable_with => "saving"` it works fine ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the property:

```
disable_with: 'button-text'
```

to the submit button solved the problem *(from comments above)*.